# OpenCV videocapture returns False when calling isOpened(), although, another code example works well

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, opencv

So, I have a Django app, that manages some USB webcameras(all Logitech C525)
This app takes frame from a `VideoCapture` object, when the `GET` request comes on specified API-endpoint and sends this frame to a server, to do some classification of object on image (usually fruits/vegetables)
App receiving requests from clients, each client's IP address(app and clients are in the same local network) is binded to unique webcam ID
Here's a snippet, that shows, how I'm searching binding between camera ID and logical device in `/dev/video*` to create a `VideoCapture` object:

```
import re
import subprocess

class CameraBinder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cam = 'C525'
        self.cam_id_list_in_dev_video = []
        self.binding_between_udev_dev = None

    def find_cam_in_dev_video(self):
        cmd = ['/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl', '--list-devices']
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = process.communicate()
        out, err = out.strip(), err.strip()
        for line in [i.split("\n\t".encode()) for i in out.split("\n\n".encode())]:
            if self.cam.encode() in line[0]:
                cam_id_from_dev = re.search(r'(?<=/dev/video).*', line[1].decode('utf-8'))
                self.cam_id_list_in_dev_video.append(cam_id_from_dev.group(0))
        process.kill()
        return self.cam_id_list_in_dev_video

    def bind_cam_between_dev_udev(self, cam_id):
        cmd = ['/bin/udevadm', 'info', '--attribute-walk', f'--name=/dev/video{cam_id}']
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = process.communicate()
        out, err = out.strip(), err.strip()
        kernel_for_udev_rules = re.search(r'(?<=KERNELS==\")[^\"]*', out.decode('utf-8')).group(0)
        serial = re.search(r'(?<=ATTRS{serial}==\")[^\"]*', out.decode('utf-8')).group(0)
        self.binding_between_udev_dev = f'{kernel_for_udev_rules} {serial}'
        process.kill()
        return self.binding_between_udev_dev
```

Than, I have some Django management commands, that are configurating my system (collecting camera IDs on first setup and binding of local IPs to this IDs)
In my `views.py` I have this endpoint:

```
from camera.utils import VideoCamera, CameraBinder
from camera.models import Binding

cam_binder = CameraBinder()
cam_list = cam_binder.find_cam_in_dev_video()
for cam_id in cam_list:
    index = cam_binder.bind_cam_between_dev_udev(cam_id)
    streams[index] = VideoCamera(cam_id)
    print(cam_id, index)
    streams[index].update_frame()


def detect(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        camera_id = Binding.objects.get(ip_address=ip).port_id
        print(camera_id, streams[camera_id])
        logger.info('detect method started')
        s_time = time.clock()
        image = streams[camera_id].get_frame()
```

`VideoCamera` class:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

def start_new_thread(function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        t = Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    return decorator


class VideoCamera(Thread):
    def __init__(self, cam_id):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.current_frame = None
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAMERA_SETTINGS['WIDTH'])
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAMERA_SETTINGS['HEIGHT'])
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, CAMERA_SETTINGS['FPS'])
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, CAMERA_SETTINGS['AUTOFOCUS'])
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS, CAMERA_SETTINGS['FOCUS'])
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))

    @start_new_thread
    def update_frame(self):
        while True:
            ret, self.current_frame = self.stream.read()
            if self.current_frame is None:
                time.sleep(0.100)
                continue

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.current_frame
```

When I'm running development server, it's all seems going well, but when I'm trying to send a request to my API endpoint, I'm receiving this:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2020-03-27 19:25:25,674 | INFO | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 27, 2020 - 19:25:26
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'sw_client.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2020-03-27 19:25:29,941 | INFO | detect method started
Internal Server Error: /detect/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/sw_client/camera/views.py", line 45, in detect
    cv2.imwrite(DEBUG_PATH + f'/grabbed{camera_id}.jpg', image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

2020-03-27 19:25:29,995 | ERROR | Internal Server Error: /detect/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/smart_weights/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/sw_client/camera/views.py", line 45, in detect
    cv2.imwrite(DEBUG_PATH + f'/grabbed{camera_id}.jpg', image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

[27/Mar/2020 19:25:29] "GET /detect/ HTTP/1.1" 500 79218
```

If I comment out this line of code, I'll receive an error message 2 lines after, on encoding an image to send it via JSON.
As I understood, image, that comes to `imwrite()`, is empty. I tried to print out `self.stream.isOpened()` inside the `VideoCamera()` class. And output was `False`. But at the same time, I can run this:

```
import cv2


cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# cap4 = cv2.VideoCapture(6)
while 1:

    ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, img2 = cap2.read()
    ret3, img3 = cap3.read()
    # ret4, img4 = cap4.read()

    if ret1 and ret2:

        cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
        cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
        cv2.imshow('img3', img3)
        # cv2.imshow('img4', img4)

        k = cv2.waitKey(100)
        if k == 27: #press Esc to exit
            break

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cap3.release()
# cap4.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this works, outputting me 3 windows with videostream from my cameras.
So, how can I localize a trouble? I think, this is not because of OpenCV/Python versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble in `find_cam_in_dev_video` method, it returns list of `strings`, `VideoCapture` needs `int` as an argument. Cast to `int` in:

```
for cam_id in cam_list:
    index = cam_binder.bind_cam_between_dev_udev(cam_id)
    streams[index] = VideoCamera(int(cam_id))
```

solves the problem